# Почему при установке Webpack вылезает ошибка?

Tags: javascript, webpack

прописываю в терминале команду npm install -D webpack webpack-cli

и мне выдает ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**P.S. все делал по этому видео** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSaF8NXeNsA&t=859s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прочитай сообщение об ошибке, переименуй папку и свой пакет в package.json.